# Taking filled rows from multidimmensional array which first index is string

Tags: php, arrays

I want to try take only filled rows to another array via array_push but i can't take them dynamically because first index is string, how can i do it properly? Thanks.

```
<?php
 while($i < count($val['error']){

  if($val['error'][$i] === 0)
  {
   array_push($newarray, $val[whatwilliputherebecauseofstringindex][$i]);
  }

 }
?>
```

[Hi here is the pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/2476418)

Comment: use a `foreach ($array as $key => $val)` loop. then you can use `$key`

Comment: does not work here is full code http://pastebin.ca/2476420

Comment: so you have a "before" of your array in pastebin. Show an "after" of what you expect to have

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2476421 here is before / after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// get keys of original array (name, type, etc..)
$keys = array_keys($array);
// for each error value ...
foreach ($array['error'] as $key => $val) {
  // if error is not 0..
  if($val !== 0)
  {
    // for each key in the original array.. 
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
      // unset the element of the same iteration
      unset($array[$k][$key]);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for help. If all value != 0 then print_r($array) shows only array(array()) how can i prevent this?

Comment: @AskerMan well, You wanted an array where only the `'error'` == 0. Well if none are 0 then you end up with an empty array.. what are you expecting to happen if all values != 0?

Comment: im expecting not to get null value :) by the way i solved my problem with different way, i will share with you later

Comment: @AskerMan well when all values are unset.. there's nothin' left. I guess I'm just unclear on what you actually want then.. if the condition dictates that all values are removed, that means you end up with nothing. but now you say you don't want null returned. Well you aren't *really* getting null returned; you're getting an empty array, which is exactly what is supposed to happen when all the elements are removed. I'd be interested in seeing what you did that works for you so that I can understand what exactly you actually want :)